# Progress Bar on scrolling is not working on specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have added the progress bar in the header on page scroll in Magento-2 Website. It is working fine on all pages except Product listing page.

I am using code:

```js
require(['jquery'], function() {

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      var s = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
        d = jQuery(document).height(),
        c = jQuery(window).height();
      scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
      var position = scrollPercent;

      //$("#progressbar").attr('value', position);
      jQuery("#progressbar").css('width', position + '%');

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console , what you mean by doesn't work , please be more explicit

Comment: No, there is no error in console.

Comment: so what's  happening exactly ?

Comment: progress bar is not appearing on product list page only

Comment: if you use inspect tool does it existe in your code ?

Comment: yes, It is exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162722/discussion-between-brimos-and-vinod-kumar).